# Are the settings in Visual Studio 2010 stored with the solution or with the IDE?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, ide, settings, projects-and-solutions

Are the settings in Visual Studio 2010 stored with the solution or with the IDE?

Is there any way to have settings that are the default with the IDE and then overriden by the project?

Comment: It really depends on which settings.

Comment: which setting are you referring to?

Comment: I guess I just wanted to know where I can find a reference listing which settings are stored with the IDE and which settings are stored with the solution, and which are stored with the project.

Comment: You won't get that.  Which settings are you referring to?

Comment: @Hans Okay so the toolbar settings...and the Tools->Options->Projects and Solutions->Track Active Item in Solution Explorer (thus far anyway)

Comment: @Hans I'd like to mark your answer as the correct one...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Any settings affecting the user interface, the ones you set with Tools + Options are *not* stored in solution or project files.  Nor is there a way to get a loaded solution to alter them.  They are stored in the CurrentSettings.vssettings file, Documents/Visual Studio 20xx/Settings subdirectory of your user folder.

Answer (score 1):

They can be exported and imported.  Under the `Tools` menu, check out `Import and Export Settings...`

Answer (score 0):

The VS2010 IDE settings are saved with the IDE, not with the project or solution. (Except, of course the project/solutions settings, but I assume that we're not talking about that)

After reading this [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1x6229t8.aspx) article,it seems that the common way to have different sets of configuration is using the import/export setting option having one xml file for each configuration set.

Maybe some addin could do the job, but at this time I don't know any with this features.